# Using "Previous" function in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have the below expression that works just fine,

```
=Previous(SUM(Fields!AVGCallsPerDay.Value / CountDistinct(Fields!ISOWeek.Value)),"Quarter2")
```

However, I needed to add some additional logic(IIF statement) into it(code below) but the report won't work. I get an error saying 'The use of previous aggregate function in a Tablix cell is not supported'. I have a feeling that there's a syntax error, because the above expression works just fine with "previous". I would be grateful if someone could explain what is the problem with the below expression?

```
=Previous(IIF((Fields!BranchManager.Value) = "All Branches",
SUM(Fields!AVGCallsPerDay.Value) /CountDistinct(Fields!ISOWeek.Value),
AVG(Fields!AVGCallsPerDay.Value)), "Quarter2")
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a few things that could be causing your issue with these expressions.  The first expression seems to be summing up the expression `Fields!AVGCallsPerDay.Value / CountDistinct(Fields!ISOWeek.Value)`.  You said that this works just fine and seems to be what you are intending to do.  The second equation does not use the same logic -- you are summing `Fields!AVGCallsPerDay.Value` and dividing that value by `CountDistinct(Fields!ISOWeek.Value)`.  With that said, you will likely need to adjust your parenthesis to get the same value.

The next potential issue I see is that `Previous` is the outermost function used.  I haven't tested this, but I would assume that you want the `IIF` to be the outermost function.  With these changes, I believe you'll need to rewrite your expression to the following:

```
=IIF(Fields!BranchManager.Value = "All Branches", 
     Previous(SUM(Fields!AVGCallsPerDay.Value / CountDistinct(Fields!ISOWeek.Value)),"Quarter2"), 
     Previous(AVG(Fields!AVGCallsPerDay.Value), "Quarter2"))
```